# How to check if association exists and display associated record instead of actual record.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I am trying to have the system check to see if there is a customer category, if there is, display the customer category and if not display the internal category. I tried doing something like

```
<% if c.customer_labor_category != 'nil' %>
```

I also tried the following right above where it displays "l"

```
<% if c.customer_labor_category.any? %>
```

I basically need it to check if there is a customer category if there is, use that field instead of the internal one.

```
<% c = lh.pluck('categories.category').uniq %>
   <% if c.length == 0 %>
      <tr>
         <td class="tg-multirow" rowspan="1">Category</td>
         <td class="tg-datacell"></td>
         <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="1">Effort</td>
         <td class="tg-datacell"></td>
      </tr>
   <% else %>
      <% c.each do |l| %>
        <tr>
           <% if l == c.first %>
             <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= lc.length %>">Labor Category</td>
           <% end %>
             <td class="tg-datacell"> <%= l %> </td>
             <% if l == c.first %>
                <td class="tg-celltitle" rowspan="<%= c.length %>">effort</td>
             <% end %>
            <% hours = lh.joins(:category).where(:categories => { :category => l }).each.sum(&:hours) %>
              <td class="tg-datacell"> <%= hours %></td> 
         </tr>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c.customer_labor_category.nil? # true if nil
c.customer_labor_category.present? # true if not nil
```